# php unable to create SQLite3 object and query

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite

I'm attempting to query my SQLite3 database in order to look up a record/row in a table based on a single variable.  In order to do this, I'm trying to use a SQLite3 object, and then run a querySingle function call.  My code is based on the example#1 [here](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.querysingle.php).

```
echo "entered";
$toQuery = "SELECT vlan FROM client WHERE mac=" . $clientmac;
$db = new SQLite3(getcwd() . '/system_diag_tool/system.db');
echo "created";
$clientInfo = $db->querySingle($toQuery, true);
if(empty($clientInfo)){
    echo "retured empty record...";
}
echo var_dump($clientInfo);
echo "dumped";
return $clientInfo;
```

I have done some crude echo statements which result in only the "entered" being printed out, but not the "created", leading me to believe that it is not a problem with my query, but rather the creation of the SQLite3 object.  However, what I am doing isn't very different from the example, and so I am unsure of what could be halting the execution.  Any ideas?

I have 644 permissions on my database file and 777 on the folder containing it, and even changed the .db file to 777 just to ensure that wasn't the problem.

Comment: You should try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of your code. Also, what is `$clientmac`? If it is a string it'll fail.

Comment: I bet mac is not an int, so you will need to correctly quote it as a string. WHERE mac='$clientmac'";

Comment: Okay I will.  It is a string, but why should that cause the new SQLite3() to fail?

Comment: Enable error reporting. If SQLite3 constructor is failing, you should have an error, and without it we won't be able to help.